# Create a new field from a nested field with aggregation framework, MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My document:

```
{
  currentRole: { title: "Engineer"}
}
```

Desired output

```
{
  role: "Engineer"
}
```

Tried this:

```
let query = mongoose.model('cvs').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
               "currentRole.title":1,
               "_id": 0
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

But this gives:

```
  {
    "currentRole": {
      "title": "Engineer"
    }
  },
```

How can I created a new field with the title value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your project stage to use the value of the field like this :

```
   {
        $project: {
           "role": "$currentRole.title",
           "_id": 0
        }
    }
```